# Tkinter Calculator with changing text buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to Python, and am trying to make a calculator with a Texas Instruments calculator as my inspiration for functions and functionality. Currently, I'm trying to make a shift button that changes all the text of the buttons to a different set of text. For simplicity in testing, I am working with just one button and the others are commented out. I ran my program and got the following error message:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ryanflynn/shCalctest.py", line 18, in 
    txt = root.StringVar()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/**init**.py", line 2095, in **getattr**
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'StringVar'

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
root.title('Calculator')

mode = 0

display = Entry(root)
display.grid(row = 1, columnspan = 6)


def txtupdate(mode):
    a = ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J])
    txt.set(a[mode])
    return

txt = tk.StringVar()
one = Button(root, variabletext = txt[0], command = lambda : print(txt))
txt.set([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0])
one.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
'''two = Button(root, text = '2', command = lambda : print('2'))
two.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
three = Button(root, text = '3', command = lambda : print('3'))
three.grid(row = 2, column = 2)
four = Button(root, text = '4', command = lambda : print('4'))
four.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
five = Button(root, text = '5', command = lambda : print('5'))
five.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
six = Button(root, text = '6', command = lambda : print('6'))
six.grid(row = 3, column = 2)
seven = Button(root, text = '7', command = lambda : print('7'))
seven.grid(row = 4, column = 0)
eight = Button(root, text = '8', command = lambda : print('8'))
eight.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
nine = Button(root, text = '9', command = lambda : print('9'))
nine.grid(row = 4, column = 2)
zero = Button(root, text = '0', command = lambda : print('0'))
zero.grid(row = 5, column = 1)'''
shift = Button(root, text = 'sft', command = txtupdate(1))
shift.grid(row = 2, column = 1)


root.mainloop()
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Could you give a copy of the error? Usually, if an error appears in a system file (in your case tkinter's `__init__.py` file) it's usually because of a problem with arguments in your code.

Comment: Please select an answer or comment on the answers that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You imported all from tkinter - no need for `tk.StringVar`.
2. `variabletext = txt[0]` - it's `textvariable` and the indexing is unneeded here.
3. ** `a = ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J])` - the letters are precieved as variables, which are not defined. You can replace them with `['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']`.

Change these two lines:

```
txt = StringVar()
one = Button(root, textvariable = txt, command = lambda : print(txt))
```

Comment: This was very helpful, and the error went away. I do have new problems, which I will be making a new post regarding, as they do not pertain to those asked or answered here. Thank you again!